# PHPExcel copy sheet and change

Tags: php, phpexcel

```
$inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($path . '/' . $fileName); 
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($path . '/' . $fileName);

//temp sheet copy 2 times
for ($pageIndex=1; $pageIndex <= 2; $pageIndex++) {
   $tempSheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0)->copy();
   $tempSheet->setTitle('Page ' . $pageIndex);

   $objPHPExcel->addSheet($tempSheet);
   unset($tempSheet);
}

$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(1);
$sheet->setCellValueExplicitByColumnAndRow(0, 1, 'TEST', PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING);
```

I copy a single excel sheet 2 times and I only make changes on page 2. This change applies to all pages

Comment: Don't use copy, because that's a "shallow" copy; use clone

Comment: I used clone but not change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by updating PHPExcel library version 1.7.6 to 1.8

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have no problem with your code.
That code block works even if you use copy instead of clone. 
At least, I have run on my computer and it just changed content of the first row of page 2.